# Destructuring or variable declaration in a class in React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I think this is a quick one
I am getting the following error

```
./src/components/container.js
  Line 22:7:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  20 | changeName = this.changeName.bind(this);
  21 |
> 22 | const { floors, rooms, boards, cards } = InitialData;
```

I don't understand why I am not able to destructure this here. This was working from a functional component but I am bringing it into a class now.

FULL CODE

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Floor from './floor'
import InitialData from './data/data';


export default class Container extends Component {
  state = {
    firstName:"Joy",
    place:"nirvana"
  }

const { floors, rooms, boards, cards } = InitialData;


  render() {

    return (
      <div>
<h2>Here is a container component</h2>
<Floor />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Move `const { floors, rooms, boards, cards } = InitialData;` into the `render(){`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Floor from './floor'
import InitialData from './data/data';

export default class Container extends Component {
    state = {
        firstName:"Joy",
        place:"nirvana"
    }




    render() {

        **** change this line ****
        const { floors, rooms, boards, cards } = InitialData;

        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Here is a container component</h2>
                <Floor />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```